# Error : Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, json, express, body-parser

When I hit the signup route "req.body" doesn't pick any up any of the POST values, however whenever the same code is tested on Postman - with body raw method - the values display.

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Promise = require('bluebird');

router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));


const registration = require('./services/registration');

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('Admin Welcome');
});

router.get('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('user/signup');
});

router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send(req.body);
  registration.registration(req.body);
  .then(ok=>{
    res.redirect('signin')
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.render('error', {message: err})
  })
})

router.get('/signin', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('user/signin');
});
```

[original code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiTyO.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I see you already have an answer - but you should probably edit your question to make it more clear. Posting images of code isn't the best idea - you can include code snippets and have them syntax highlighted (like in the answer given).  The clearer your question is, in general, the better the response and answers you will receive.

Comment: it's was my first experience on stack and I don't understand how write code , so i attach image , Next time i will try to post code

Comment: use `return res.send()`

Comment: @MohammadHamza - you probably can't edit yet so I have done it for you - when you get a chance you can view the edited question to see how it is formatted. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.post("/signup", (req, res, next) => {
  res.send(req.body);
  registration
    .registration(req.body)
    .then(ok => {
      res.redirect("signin");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.render("error", { message: err });
    });
});
```

The `res` object represents the HTTP response that an Express app sends when it gets an HTTP request. In the following link you can see all the methods that are exposed for `res` object:
https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res

Method that you are using at the beginning of you route handler is:

**res.send([body])**

And as it can be read from the documentation it sends the HTTP response. Now you can send that response only once, otherwise you will get an error:

```
Error : Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

And what you are trying to do in the handler is to redirect result to "signin" page afterwards already sending the response with `res.send(req.body)`.

Take this fake route for an example:

```
router.post("/example", (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('1');
  res.send('2');
  res.send('3');
});
```

Contrary to what you might believe, it wont return values (1,2,3), but actually return value 1 and raise and error that was previously described.

Finally to solve your issue you need to remove line containing `res.send(req.body)` and double check if `registration.registration` service is correctly handling provided data, in this case `req.body`.

Comment: i use  res.send(req.body) just for see that data come or not

Comment: I understand that you are using it for debugging, but using `res.send` method for it is plain wrong. In this case it is better to use `console.log` or debugger.

Comment: but how i resolve my problem ... I removed  res.send but result stil no come

Comment: Double check if  `registration.registration` service is correctly handling provided data, and that it is in fact creating user properly. Also check if  `user/signin` page is existing and if it is named correctly.

Comment: all functionality properly working , when i use postman body json method result shown but in form case result not shown